# typeerror begin is undefined - firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this menu

```
<div id="toptest"></div><div id="cover" style="position:relative;z-index:800;">
    <div id="header">
        Lumen Photography
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li><a href="#" alt="toptest" class="subinfo">Home<span>Welkom!</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" alt="wie" class="subinfo">Wie zijn we<span>Info over ons</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" alt="contact" class="subinfo">Contact<span>(Aan)vraag</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" alt="ref" class="subinfo">Referenties<span>Enkele namen...</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="position:fixed;width:100%;top:0px;z-index:600;box-shadow:0px 0px 6px black">
<div id="mainmenu">
    <ul id="yw0">
            <li><a href="#" alt="toptest" class="subinfo">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" alt="wie" class="subinfo">Wie zijn we</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" alt="contact" class="subinfo">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" alt="ref" class="subinfo">Referentie</a></li>
```

It's 2 menus. They're actually the same but one is behind the others and appears if you scroll down (i don't want to use the semi fixed header that appears on scroll. Lags on slow pc's).

This javascript declarations:

```
 <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jqueryui.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.animate-colors.js"></script>  
 <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
```

and jquery.js declared entirely at the top.

I have 
    var co;
    $('.subinfo').hover(
        function(){
            co = $(this).css('color');
            $(this).children().stop().animate({opacity:1}, 200);

```
        $(this).children().animate({color:returnColor()},100);
        $(this).stop().animate({color:returnColor()},100);
    },
    function(){                
        $(this).children('span').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 200);
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', color:co});
    }
);
```

as event listener.

In chrome, it works. In firefox, it works just to hover, but not to leave. It gives me the error: typeError: begin is undefined (r:76 in animate-colors) but that animate colors is a jquery plugin. i used it before and i never experienced this problem..

what do?

Comment: what's the value of the variable `co` inside the second (un-hover) function? This is not a real question hehe

Comment: Nothing. It's just var co; co is defined in the first hover function. and it is a question. Why does it not work in firefox? How do i fix this? It gives me an error when I un-hover...

Comment: ok sorry, that missing line was important hehe. Read my answer, I hope it's a real answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems firefox needs to know the initial `background-color` of the element you are animating. So you have to add it before the animation starts:

```css
.subinfo {
    background-color:white;
}
```

If you want to animate a color, it's important to know both the end color and the initial one. I don't know why Chrome doesn't fail or what color is using as starting point...

it should work with that, if not, post a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks. I guessed it was that, too. But it wasn't. It had something to do with backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'

I removed it. Now it works. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's because `255,255,255,0` means Red=255, Green=255, Blue=255, Alpha=0, that is: `transparent`. If you change alpha to 0.1 it works again. Makes sense, transparent is not a color hehe